# Qt: QMouseEvent - How to get widget

Tags: qt

I am using `QMouseEvent` and `QKeyEvents` in my program. I programmatically make various widgets (`QDockWidgets` and `QCustomPlots`).

I would like to use a single click and keypress handler function. However, I am struggling to get the widget that is actually being clicked, so that I can do certain stuff within that widget.

Is there a way to return from a `ClickEvent` the name of the widget that was clicked?

Comment: Since those events are delivered to particular objects, you already know what widget is receiving them. Or else I really don't understand what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `eventFilter` in your mainWindow and listen for events from widgets there :

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * event)
{

    if((myWidget *)obj == widget1 && event->type()==QEvent::KeyPress) 
    {

        int pressedKey = ((QKeyEvent*)event)->key();

        ...

    }
    else if((myWidget *)obj == widget2 && event->type()==QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
    {

        if(((QMouseEvent*)event)->button() == Qt::LeftButton)
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Also do not forget to install event filters for your widgets in the mainWindow constructor :

```
widget1->installEventFilter(this);
widget2->installEventFilter(this);
```